# Configuring Spring Social to serve static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-social

I am currently using Spring Boot and Spring Social to allow people to log in using Facebook, Twitter, or LinkedIn, within my project, which is based on an already existing Spring project -

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/quickstart/config

I want to be able to serve static content (CSS, JS, Images) within my project. I am also using Thymeleaf to template my views. The problem is that when I run the project, Spring can't find the static content. I have researched on other websites and found an article -

http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-static/

that said that if your static content was in a /resources folder, Spring would be able to find it. Other articles and projects that I've looked at are -

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static
- https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Here is a picture of my file tree and where the files are located.

[image: File Tree]

Here is the signin.html page

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/signin/facebook}" method="POST">
    <button id="facebookloginelementbutton" type="submit" class="loginelementbutton">Login with <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></button>

    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email,publish_stream,offline_access" />
</form>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need to see more files or if I am going about this wrong, please tell me!

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have project structure like below, static folder inside resources folder, then inside static folder you can have `css, images, js etc`:

[image: Project Structure]

Then CSS is referred in the code like:

```
<link href="/assets/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and javascripts like:

```
<script src="/assets/js/project_angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have updated the question as I included the wrong file tree screenshot. This screenshot shows the src/main/resources/static folder that I was using initially. It still doesn't work that way. I have also tried META-INF/resources, /resources, and /public.

Comment: You have only index.css under static folder, you need to move views folder also under static folder. Please check my screenshot, I have static folder under resources and then all css, js etc under the assets folder (assets folder is under static folder).